# How do I implement money transfer via paypal in react native?

Tags: react-native, paypal

I have a react native app where I have details of users email and phone numbers. I want the app to transfer money from the user to another user of the app. What options do I have?

I viewed checkout implementations on youtube and [react-native-paypal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal) but they don't seem to serve my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android apps and iOS apps, in-apps are encouraged to be used to pay for the app, otherwise the app review may reject it. Therefore, it is advisable for you to use the Inapp. The following modules can be recommended:

### React-native-iap

[image]

### Example

```js
import {
  Alert,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import RNIap, {
  Product,
  ProductPurchase,
  PurchaseError,
  acknowledgePurchaseAndroid,
  purchaseErrorListener,
  purchaseUpdatedListener,
} from 'react-native-iap';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import NativeButton from 'apsl-react-native-button';

// App Bundle > com.dooboolab.test

const itemSkus = Platform.select({
  ios: [
    'com.cooni.point1000',
    'com.cooni.point5000', // dooboolab
  ],
  android: [
    'android.test.purchased',
    'android.test.canceled',
    'android.test.refunded',
    'android.test.item_unavailable',
    // 'point_1000', '5000_point', // dooboolab
  ],
});

const itemSubs = Platform.select({
  ios: [
    'com.cooni.point1000',
    'com.cooni.point5000', // dooboolab
  ],
  android: [
    'test.sub1', // subscription
  ],
});

let purchaseUpdateSubscription;
let purchaseErrorSubscription;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: Platform.select({
      ios: 0,
      android: 24,
    }),
    paddingTop: Platform.select({
      ios: 0,
      android: 24,
    }),
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  header: {
    flex: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headerTxt: {
    fontSize: 26,
    color: 'green',
  },
  content: {
    flex: 80,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  btn: {
    height: 48,
    width: 240,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#00c40f',
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
  },
  txt: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'white',
  },
});

class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      productList: [],
      receipt: '',
      availableItemsMessage: '',
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount(): void {
    try {
      const result = await RNIap.initConnection();
      await RNIap.consumeAllItemsAndroid();
      console.log('result', result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err.code, err.message);
    }

    purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener(
      async (purchase: ProductPurchase) => {
        console.log('purchaseUpdatedListener', purchase);
        if (
          purchase.purchaseStateAndroid === 1 &&
          !purchase.isAcknowledgedAndroid
        ) {
          try {
            const ackResult = await acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(
              purchase.purchaseToken,
            );
            console.log('ackResult', ackResult);
          } catch (ackErr) {
            console.warn('ackErr', ackErr);
          }
        }
        this.setState({ receipt: purchase.transactionReceipt }, () =>
          this.goNext(),
        );
      },
    );

    purchaseErrorSubscription = purchaseErrorListener(
      (error: PurchaseError) => {
        console.log('purchaseErrorListener', error);
        Alert.alert('purchase error', JSON.stringify(error));
      },
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount(): void {
    if (purchaseUpdateSubscription) {
      purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove();
      purchaseUpdateSubscription = null;
    }
    if (purchaseErrorSubscription) {
      purchaseErrorSubscription.remove();
      purchaseErrorSubscription = null;
    }
  }

  goNext = (): void => {
    Alert.alert('Receipt', this.state.receipt);
  };

  getItems = async (): void => {
    try {
      const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
      // const products = await RNIap.getSubscriptions(itemSkus);
      console.log('Products', products);
      this.setState({ productList: products });
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err.code, err.message);
    }
  };

  getSubscriptions = async (): void => {
    try {
      const products = await RNIap.getSubscriptions(itemSubs);
      console.log('Products', products);
      this.setState({ productList: products });
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err.code, err.message);
    }
  };

  getAvailablePurchases = async (): void => {
    try {
      console.info(
        'Get available purchases (non-consumable or unconsumed consumable)',
      );
      const purchases = await RNIap.getAvailablePurchases();
      console.info('Available purchases :: ', purchases);
      if (purchases && purchases.length > 0) {
        this.setState({
          availableItemsMessage: `Got ${purchases.length} items.`,
          receipt: purchases[0].transactionReceipt,
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err.code, err.message);
      Alert.alert(err.message);
    }
  };

  // Version 3 apis
  requestPurchase = async (sku): void => {
    try {
      RNIap.requestPurchase(sku);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err.code, err.message);
    }
  };

  requestSubscription = async (sku): void => {
    try {
      RNIap.requestSubscription(sku);
    } catch (err) {
      Alert.alert(err.message);
    }
  };

  render(): React.ReactElement {
    const { productList, receipt, availableItemsMessage } = this.state;
    const receipt100 = receipt.substring(0, 100);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerTxt}>react-native-iap V3</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <ScrollView style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <View style={{ height: 50 }} />
            <NativeButton
              onPress={this.getAvailablePurchases}
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              style={styles.btn}
              textStyle={styles.txt}
            >
              Get available purchases
            </NativeButton>

            <Text style={{ margin: 5, fontSize: 15, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
              {availableItemsMessage}
            </Text>

            <Text style={{ margin: 5, fontSize: 9, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
              {receipt100}
            </Text>

            <NativeButton
              onPress={(): void => this.getItems()}
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              style={styles.btn}
              textStyle={styles.txt}
            >
              Get Products ({productList.length})
            </NativeButton>
            {productList.map((product, i) => {
              return (
                <View
                  key={i}
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                  }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      marginTop: 20,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: 'black',
                      minHeight: 100,
                      alignSelf: 'center',
                      paddingHorizontal: 20,
                    }}
                  >
                    {JSON.stringify(product)}
                  </Text>
                  <NativeButton
                    // onPress={(): void => this.requestPurchase(product.productId)}
                    onPress={(): void =>
                      this.requestSubscription(product.productId)
                    }
                    activeOpacity={0.5}
                    style={styles.btn}
                    textStyle={styles.txt}
                  >
                    Request purchase for above product
                  </NativeButton>
                </View>
              );
            })}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

You may want to use two together, so we'll also leave a link to PayPal below. [paypal link](https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/integrating-paypal-in-your-react-native-app-4dcf89e11dd)

Comment: @Anirudh If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' sign and arrow for my answer?

Comment: I agree with you. But I don't want the money to be go into my account. Just transfer from one user's paypal to another user's paypal account.

Comment: @Anirudh I left a link for PayPal below, too.

Comment: Got it. Thank you